# .htaccess on 000webhost options

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

I am trying to modify my `.htaccess` file in 000webhost in order to disable **Indexes** option only for a specific folder (because it is enabled by default).

I have all the following files in `public_html/` folder:

- nas/ (empty directory)
- test/ (empty directory)
- .htaccess

I would like to disable the Indexes options in `test/` folder, but keep that option enabled on `nas/`. I have tried with the following **Directory** container but it makes the site crash:

```
<Directory /public_html/test/>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

I have been trying many different paths (because as far as I know, 000webhost uses virtual routers, but I can't find the way to do it).

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to disable the Indexes option for `/test` folder you can go with

```
<Directory "/public_html/test/">
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

**Option -Indexes** will remove completely the access to the test folder in the repo.

If you want to keep the Indexes option for only `/nas` folder so that outsider can have access to this folder contains then you can go with the following

```
<Directory "/public_html/nas/">
   Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <Directory /public_html/nas/>
>     Options -Indexes
> </Directory>
> ```

The `<Directory>` directive is not permitted in `.htaccess` (hence your 500 error). `<Directory>` containers can only be used in a *server* or *virtualhost* context. The `.htaccess` file itself is the equivalent of the `<Directory>` container. (But why are you trying to target the `/nas` directory here, since it would seem to be the `/test` subdirectory that you want to *disable* directory listings for?)

You will need to create another `.htaccess` file in the `/test` subdirectory in which you disable directory listings:

```
# Disable auto-generated directory listings (mod_autoindex) for this directory only
Options -Indexes
```

Now, you'll just get a 403 Forbidden when accessing the `/test` subdirectory.

Alternatively, if you don't want to create another `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory then you'll need to use `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias) or `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) to block that specific URL. For example, in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^test/?$ - [F]
```

The above will also trigger a 403 when attempting to access the `/test/` subdirectory directly (just as if the `Indexes` option were disabled for that subdirectory). All files within that subdirectory (if any) are still accessible.

Comment: How did you get on with this?